# Connection between angles in ray optics and phases in wave optics

Tags: optics, waves, geometric-optics

In ray optics, angles (or say, ray deflections) describe how rays will displace in propagation.

In wave optics, phases (or say, wavefronts) are the phase part of the complex representations, e.g. $\phi$ in scalar field $A \exp(\rm j \phi)$.

Following figure shows my intuition.

[image]

*Black: rays; Red: phases.*

Questions:

1. How are they (intuitively) connected to each other?

   From a trigor optics perspective, I found a beautiful article shows a connection between rays (light field) and waves (Wigner function): https://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/lfwigner/.
2. Under what situation should we prefer one to another?

   For exmaple, when analyzing daily cameras and photography, we talk about angles, in ray optics; when dealing with phase contrast microscopy or interferometry where distortions are very small, we talk about phases, in wave optics.
3. Can I apply phase concepts in large scale applications and replace rays?

   For example, instead of saying

   > "at point $x$, a ray deflects at 0.1 rad"

   Can I say

   > "at point $x$, the phase is $200 \lambda$ every 1 mm (with $\lambda = 500$ nm)"

Comment: In an isotropic medium the rays are orthogonal to the wave fronts (constant phase surfaces). That these is true after arbitrary number of refractions and reflections is called Malus theorem. The existence of such surfaces for a ray system is equivalent to Fermat's principle. All of these are true only in the far field of the EM wave (light) source.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for the point out. So my question should limit to “isotopic medium+visible lights (sufficiently small wavelength)”.

Comment: since I have not read the Wigner function reference I cannot comment on  that but if the medium is not *isotRopic* ("R") then the behavior of light waves - rays depends on their direction and the situation is much more complicated, see e.g., crystal optics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_optics

Comment: @hyportnex right. So I should say this question only considers free space propagation.